# Can I match the beginning of a substring if I specify `startat`?

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\b");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("x 10", 2));           // False
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("x 10".Substring(2))); // True
```

Is there a character to use in my pattern besides `^` that will let me specify a `startat` parameter and still yield the same results as taking the equivalent substring? In other words, can I match the beginning of the substring I'm testing, even if it's not necessarily the beginning of the string I'm passing in? I will be moving the regex along the string, so I don't want to create a ton of substrings and I can't hardcode it into my pattern.

Comment: `.IsMatch(String, Int32)` returning false seems odd...

Comment: @ephemient—That's what I thought.

Comment: No, it's not odd.  Apparently IsMatch even with a `startat` value specified considers the entire string context.  Thus, the "beginning of line" anchor (i.e. `^`) will fail if starting in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try `\G`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions), eg:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\G\d+\b");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("x 10", 2));
```

[`\G`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) matches at the point where the previous match ended (or start of string of not matched before).

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thanks! http://www.regular-expressions.info failed me on this one.

Comment: [www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) explains the \G anchor, but it doesn't really address this use case.

Answer (score -2):

var regex = new Regex(@"\w\t\d+\b");

Comment: Sorry, my question was ambiguous. I reworded it. (Note also that `\t` matches a tab, not a space.)

Comment: try 
var regex = new Regex(@"[\w]*\d+\b");

Comment: I want to make sure that my pattern is the very first thing being matched at whatever starting position I specify. You're too hung up on my specific example.

Comment: try this var regex = new Regex(@"$`\<\d+\>$'");

Comment: You should probably be updating your answer rather than continuing to post comments. Either way, I'm not quite sure where you got your last pattern from...